# How to hint the type of self variable in Python

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting

Usually it is unnecessary to care the `self` variable in a Python class member function, but I am implementing a decorator, looks like

```
def extractor(depends: List[Text]=None,
              provides: List[Text]=None) -> Callable[[ExtractorFunction],
                                                     ExtractorFunction]:
    def _func_wrapper(func: ExtractorFunction) -> ExtractorFunction:
        func.is_extractor = True    # The value is not important through
        func.depends = depends
        func.provides = provides

        @functools.wraps(func)
        def _wrapper(self, parsed: CCDATA, target: ExtractResult) -> None:
            func(self, parsed, target)
        return _wrapper
    return _func_wrapper
```

which is intended to use like this:

```
class Extractor():
    @extractor()
    def _extractor_for_xxx(self, parsed: CCDATA, target: ExtractResult) -> None:
        pass
```

`ExtractResult` is well defined, yet I am not sure how to define `ExtractorFunction` type. Any ideas?